# Would the bugcheck code CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION be caused by a unhandled exception or is the kernel calling KeBugCheckEx directly?

Tags: c, exception

I'm trying to understand the relation between a bug check and an exception in the case where when the kernel detects that a function has been modified and issues a CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION value. Is the kernel calling KeBugCheckEx directly or would it be caused by an unhandled exception. I'm really confused and believe that my understanding is not correct so please correct my poor understanding of these two concepts. On the Microsoft website the documentation for [CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x109---critical-structure-corruption) there is no mention of any exception code, exception address and so on.

Comment: CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION is related to PatchGuard, a security-critical system that appears to be fairly obfuscated. You may need to do extensive reverse-engineering to discover your answer; I had a quick peek into my copy of ntoskrnl + symbols and was not able to gain a significant understanding of where/when it may call KeBugCheckEx. Even the sequence `MOV ECX,0x109` (as I'd expect for a direct call to KeBugCheckEx) is exceedingly rare. Perhaps with a kernel dump that has an intact stack for a CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION bugcheck and good insight, you may get further.

Comment: Adding to the above, actually getting CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION on your machine should be fairly straightforward if you have kernel-mode control: just tamper with one of the things listed in the docs that it checks.

Comment: @nanofarad thank you. I am working with ByePg the open source project a bypass of Patchguard and unfortunately I am not able to modify this code to address CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION bugcheck due to the lack of Microsoft documentation.

Comment: Rather than *documentation*, you probably need hands on *investigation*. It's intentionally undocumented, but (as I suggested before), a kernel dump with an intact stack, memory, etc might let you do some dynamic analysis to complement the more common static analysis that one would do with Ida, Ghidra, or other similar tools.